# Why NodeJS REST API doesnot return the whole response object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using **NodeJS** to build an **RESTAPI** . I am using **mongoose** to connect to **mongdb**. I have an api like this

```
  // Create a new route with the /beers/:beer_id prefix
var beerRoute = router.route('/beers/:beer_id');

// Create endpoint /api/beers/:beer_id for GET
beerRoute.get(function(req, res) {
  // Use the Beer model to find a specific beer
  Beer.findById(req.params.beer_id, function(err, beer) {
    if (err)
    res.send(err);
    res.json(beer);
  });
});
```

which give me response as

```
{
 "_id": "569763b60e2c584d39a53349",
 "__v": 0
}
```

What we have to do to get the whole response ?Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does "whole response object" mean?  What are you expecting?

Comment: response meaning that whole scheme i mean like {
"_id":"569763b60e2c584d39a53349",
"name":calrsberg,
"quantity":5
}

Comment: Did you insert `console.log(beer)` to see what you're actually getting back?

Comment: yes it gives the same response as mentioned above. Isn't it supposed to give results as per Schema we define ?

Comment: I don't know mongoose myself, but looking at its doc, it looks like you might use `.select()` before the query in order to determine which fields you want returned.

Comment: i tried it but its not working .

Comment: So wait, the console.log on the server side does show all the fields?

Comment: no it does not  i was going through this  document http://scottksmith.com/blog/2014/05/05/beer-locker-building-a-restful-api-with-node-crud/ it does not return me the whole response

Comment: If `console.log` on the server doesn't print the fields either...then those are the objects as they are on the db. are you sure that those objects exists as you want them on the db and your beer schema is defined correctly?

Comment: yes, if i use the mongochef its showing all the documents

Comment: Did you add the name, quantity and other fields after you already pushed data into your collection ? If so, neither mongoose nor mongodb will add the new fields to the documents that were already inserted in your database. You need to manually update these old documents so they match your new schema.